# Serialize object in Cocos2D-x

Tags: c++, serialization, cocos2d-x

What is the common (best practice) way to serialize and save objects in Cocos2D-x? We can't use NSCoding etc. But I'd really like to continue with this pattern. Ie we can serialize one object and any objects and data it contains will be nicely serialized too, as long as the NSCoding stuff is implementing on all classes that will support it.

I'll be saving model data like pretty standard strings, integers, doubles and arrays (std::vectors if you will) and dictionaries (std::map etc) really). I tried out CCNSCoder recently (existing at github) and it looked promising but unfortunately I found out that the features are limited and it's actually full of bugs.